# Force client code to call Service classes instead of Repository classes

Tags: c#, service, repository

I am using the architecture Client Code ---> Business Service ---> Repository.

Repository classes implement IRepository interface, and Service classes take IRepository as parameter in its constructor passed to it by Client Code.

Now the question is, should client code be able to directly call repository classes beside just instantiating it to pass it to service classes? In my opinion client code should be able to call repository class functions **ONLY** through service classes which applies business rules before calling the repository. Because calling repository classes directly without passing by the business layer will simply cause invalid data according to the domain business rules.

But the question is how do I prevent client code from calling methods in the repository directly while keeping the service classes depending on the abstracted IRepository interface. In other words, I need to make client code be able to instantiate the repository classes, then pass them to the service classes, but at the same time be unable to directly call the methods within the repository classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, `ClientCode` should not have awareness of `IRepository` or its implementations. This can be done with an **Inversion of Control (IoC) Container**.

An IoC Container will inject the implementation of `IRepository` into your `Service` for you without having the Client Code have an awareness of `IRepository` or its implementations. That way you can keep your dependency injection in your Service without having to open your `IRepository` interface and implementations to `ClientCode`.

For C#, two examples of IoC Containers are [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/) and [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Comment: Great solution, but the IRepository will still be visible to the ClientCode, so the developer could still mistakenly instantiate an new instance of it and access the database causing business invalid data. How can we overcome this?

Comment: Your code will look something like this: `ClientCode.Service = IoC.Resolve<ServiceClass>();` so the ClientCode relies on the container to resolve the dependencies (IRepository) instead of passing the dependencies to the service. The ClientCode will only have knowledge of the service and IoC Container.